# How to configure ansible under cygwin to use pageant (running ansible with password protected key)

Tags: ansible, cygwin, pageant

I want to use a password protected ppk file to access my servers via ansible.
I've loaded the key using pageant
I'm trying to run a simple ansible command but it fails.

> 1.1.1.1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
> "changed": false,
> "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Host key verification failed.",
> "unreachable": true
> }

How can I make sure ansible uses the key ?

My ansible is running inside cygwin terminal running on windows 10.
I think that the cygwin can't see the pageant running on the win 10 host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ppk keys needs to be transformed using puttygen to OpenSSH key
Than - you need to use
ssh-agent bash
ssh-add ./ssh_key

and than, ansible will work with that key.